# React button with scss not working poperly

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

This is my SCSS for the segment

```
    .segment {
        &__inActive {
            width: 160px;
            height: 55px;
    background-color: red;
    
        }
        &__active {
           width: 160px;
            height: 55px;
    background-color: black;
        }
    }
```

I am simplifying the scss like below but it is not working.

```
  .segment {
  
                width: 160px;
                height: 55px;
            
            &__inActive {
                background-color: #f2f2f2;
                color: #333333;
             background-color: red;
        
            }
            &__active {
                background-color: $color-blue1;
                color: #ffffff;
               background-color: black;
            }
        }
```

calling like below but it's not working can someone resolve this.

```
className={ i === activeIndex
                        ? 'segment__active'
                        : 'segment__inActive'}
```

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description. What does happen? Why is that wrong?

Comment: If you want `__active` and `__inActive` to be appended to `__dim`, why are they not nested within it? And in `__dimn__`, where does that `n` come from?

Comment: @underscore_d there were some typo issues apologies for that.  i have updated my question please check it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
 className={`${i === activeIndex? 'segment__dimn__active' : 'segment__dimn__inActive'}`}
```

Comment: What did you change, and why do you think it resolves the problem? A good answer would explain, not just drop code.